# How to handle login flow that redirects to external domain in iOS pwa/web-app to avoid address bar appearing

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, msal.js, ios-web-app

We are trying to implement basic PWA functionality for our angular 10 web app on iOS (for now, just loading it via home screen icon for ease of access).

It loads our login page fine.
We are using azure b2c auth with msal-angular. We are using redirect flow as im pretty sure there were issues with popups on mobile safari.
When a user selects 'login' they are routed to azure.

The pwa recognises it as another domain and the url bar appears with the 'done' button to return to the 'home' domain. However when returning to the app via the azure logon flow, the url bar does not go away.
If you then select 'done' in the address bar, you are booted back to the login page and have to login again to repeat the cycle, otherwise, the address bar must remain forever.

Is there a way to force the PWA to recognise you are 'back' in the correct domain again? Or an example of how to handle a login flow that goes to a different domain in an iOS PWA app?

Thanks for your help.